# Eclipse - plugin runtime classpath

Tags: eclipse

I have plugin project and it needs to use custom build of objectweb asm library.

I have that objectweb asm library as normal java project.

The problem is that i can't find how i can add external class folder (or other way) to plugin runtime classpath. It only allows me to add folder that is under that plugin project, but i want to add folder from other project.
I could import output from the library project to plugin project, but this will need to manually actualize everytime i made some changes in library project.

Any solution except converting library project to another plugin? (i want to keep it as normal java project).

Comment: Referencing something in a non-plugin project would make it very difficult to install your plugin in another Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449: why? I expect that these .class files on plugin runtime classpath will be included in plugin .jar, so where is problem?

Comment: Only files in the plugin are included in the plugin jar

Comment: @greg-449: ah ok, i thought it is possible somehow to include even other .jars. It means i need to convert all my library projects to plugin projects :(